# Proof by induction on wffs

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

Here is an extra problem form Enderton: Let $\alpha$ be a formula in sentential logic. Prove that there is some tautologically equivalent formula in which negation (if it occurs at all) is applied only to sentence symbols.

I realize that the proof is by induction. First, if $\alpha$ is a sentence symbol, then it's equivalent to itself, in which negation does not occur at all. So the base case holds.

But I'm unsure about the inductive steps.

First, suppose $\alpha = (\neg \beta)$ for some sentence $\beta$ that is equivalent to some sentence in which negation (if it occurs) is only applied to sentence symbols. How do I now show that $\alpha$ satisfies the property we want.

Second, suppose $\alpha = (\alpha_1 \square \alpha_2)$ where $\square \in \{\land, \vee, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow\}$ and $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ satisfy the desired property. How do I show that $\alpha$ now satisfies it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second step is trivial - $\alpha$ has no negations that weren't in $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. So any negation in $\alpha$ is in either $\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_2$; and any negation in $\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_2$ is applied only to sentence symbols.

In the first case, there are several sub-cases. Suppose $\beta$ is just a sentence symbol - then we're done. Suppose instead that $\beta$ is of the form $\gamma \wedge \delta$. Then $\neg\beta = \neg(\gamma \wedge \delta) \equiv \neg\gamma \vee \neg\delta$. Since $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are of strictly lower complexity than $\beta$, by induction $\neg\gamma$ and $\neg\delta$ have the desired property, so $\neg\gamma\vee\neg\delta$ does as well.

I'll let you work out the other sub-cases for yourself - they'll be similar.

EDIT: In more detail:

A wff has complexity zero if it is a sentence symbol. If $\alpha$ has complexity $n$, then $\neg\alpha$ has complexity $n+1$. The complexity of $\beta\square\gamma$ for $\square$ a connective is $1+n$, where $n$ is the maximum of the complexities of $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

We prove by induction on complexity of formula that every wff is equivalent to a wff in which negations apply only to sentence symbols.

The case of complexity zero is trivial: if $\alpha$ has complexity zero, $\alpha$ is a sentence symbol, so $\neg\alpha$ is a wff in which negations apply only to sentence symbols.

Suppose now that the claim is true for wffs of complexity at most $n$, and let $\alpha$ be a wff of complexity $n+1$. Then $\alpha$ takes one of the forms $\neg\beta$, $\gamma\wedge\delta$, $\gamma\vee\delta$, etc.

Suppose $\alpha$ is $\gamma\square\delta$ for some connective $\square$. $\gamma$ and $\delta$ both have complexity at most $n$, since $\alpha$ has complexity $n+1$; so by the induction hypothesis, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are equivalent to wffs $\gamma'$ and $\delta'$ respectively so that in each negations only apply to sentence symbols. Then $\gamma'\square\delta'$ is equivalent to $\alpha$ and has the desired property.

Suppose instead that $\alpha$ is $\neg\beta$. Then $\beta$ has complexity $n$. If $\beta$ is of the form $\neg\gamma$, then $\gamma$ has complexity less than $n$, so has an equivalent formula $\gamma'$ with the desired property; but $\gamma'$ is equivalent to $\alpha$, so we're done.

On the other hand, if $\beta$ takes the form (for example) $\gamma\wedge\delta$, then $\gamma$ and $\delta$ each have complexity less than $n$. $\neg(\gamma\wedge\delta) \equiv \neg\gamma\vee\neg\delta$, by DeMorgan's laws. $\neg\gamma$ has complexity one more than that of $\gamma$; but $\gamma$ had complexity strictly less than $n$, so $\neg\gamma$ has complexity at most $n$. Therefore, by the induction hypothesis, $\neg\gamma$ is equivalent to a wff $\gamma'$ in which negation applies only to sentence symbols. Likewise, $\neg\delta$ has an equivalent wff $\delta'$ of the desired sort. Then $\gamma'\vee\delta'$ is equivalent to $\alpha$, and has the desired property.

It remains to show the induction for the connectives $\vee$, $\to$, and $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: How does it follow by induction that $\neg \gamma$ and $\neg \delta$ have the desired property?  Can't we just conclude that $\gamma$ and $\delta$ have it?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 A proof by induction on complexity of formula operates by showing the claim for all formulas of a given complexity at each step. When we consider $\neg\beta$, we are working on the formulas with complexity $n+1$, where $\beta$ has complexity $n$; that means we've already shown the claim for complexity $n$. As subformulas of $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ have complexity at most $n - 1$, so $\neg\gamma$ and $\neg\delta$ have complexity at most $n$, putting them within the collection of formulas for which we've already proven the claim.

Comment: I see. How is complexity of a formula defined? Also, in the general framework of induction, what is the base set, sentence symbols still? And what are the operations being used--conjunction, negation, etc.?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 You may want to review the relevant definitions in Enderton - look at any proof by induction on formulas for an example. Complexity of formula is defined inductively: sentence symbols have complexity zero, and each operator ($\neg$,$\wedge$, etc.) increases the complexity by one. The base case is complexity zero, which is sentence symbols. The operations you already listed in your original question.

Comment: So does the complexity of a wff just amount to the number of connectives in it?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Unfortunately it's been a long time since I looked at Enderton, so I'm not even positive it's explicitly mentioned (though if not, it should be). If there are any inductive proofs about formulas, they should begin with "we prove by induction on complexity of formula" - this is the definition of complexity being used there. And yes, it's the number of connectives (counting $\neg$ as a connective, even though it doesn't really "connect" anything).

Comment: Ok, I get the general framework now. But the actual proof still confuses me. We assumed that the claims holds for any wff of complexity at most $n$. We also showed the claim holds for any sentence symbol. Now we want to show that it's true for any wff of complexity $n+1$? I don't think this is exactly right.

Comment: If you'd be willing, maybe you could add to your answer an expanded explanation of the specific induction proof you use. I know you gave an explanation already as an earlier comment, but I'm still struggling with what is being assumed/proven.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Added a more elaborate explanation. One note: complexity isn't connective count, it's *depth*. It's the maximum number of steps down you can go by peeling off one connective at a time.

Comment: Thank you! Last thing: for the complexity zero case are you saying that $\neg \alpha \equiv \alpha$?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 No, that's never true, of course. I'm saying $\neg\alpha$ satisfies the condition as well (for $\alpha$ complexity zero, $\alpha$ itself is the desired formula). You'll notice that in my induction step, I didn't consider the case in which $\alpha$ is $\neg\beta$ and $\beta$ is a sentence symbol; that's because I handled it in the base case.